# Scanned and found bluetooth device (thermal pxrinter) but cannot connect and print

Tags: flutter, android-bluetooth

This is the vid I follow:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46x7EONbA5w
And here is my print_page (edited along with fix recommendation):

```
import 'package:bluetooth_print/bluetooth_print.dart';
import 'package:bluetooth_print/bluetooth_print_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class PrintPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> data;
  const PrintPage(this.data, {super.key});

  @override
  _PrintPageStage createState() {
    return _PrintPageStage();
  } 
}

class _PrintPageStage extends State<PrintPage> {
  BluetoothPrint bluetoothPrint = BluetoothPrint.instance;
  List<BluetoothDevice> _devices = [];
  String _devicesMsg = "";
  final f = NumberFormat("\$###,###.00", "en_US");

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => initPrinter());
  }

  Future<void> initPrinter() async {
    bluetoothPrint.startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 2));

    if(!mounted) return;
    bluetoothPrint.scanResults.listen((val) {
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() => _devices = val);
        if (_devices.isEmpty) {
          setState(() {
          _devicesMsg = "No Devices";
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Select Printer'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: _devices.isEmpty
      ? Center(
        child:  Text(_devicesMsg),
        )
      : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _devices.length,
          itemBuilder: (c, i) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.print),
              title: Text(_devices[i].name.toString()),
              subtitle: Text(_devices[i].address.toString()),
              onTap: () {
                _startPrint(_devices[i]);
              },
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }

  Future<void> _startPrint(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    if (device.address != null) {
      await bluetoothPrint.connect(device);

      List<LineText> list = [];

      list.add(
        LineText(
          type: LineText.TYPE_TEXT,
          content: "Grocery",
          weight: 2,
          height: 2,
          align: LineText.ALIGN_CENTER,
          linefeed: 1,
        ),
      );

      for(var i = 0; i <widget.data.length; i++) {
        list.add(
          LineText(
            type:  LineText.TYPE_TEXT,
            content: widget.data[i]['name'],
            weight: 0,
            align: LineText.ALIGN_LEFT,
            linefeed: 1,
          )
        );

        list.add(
          LineText(
            type: LineText.TYPE_TEXT,
            content: 
                "${f.format(widget.data[i]['price'])} x ${widget.data[i]['qty']}",
            align: LineText.ALIGN_LEFT,
            linefeed: 1,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Like the title, I found the printer on list but on tap, it does nothing.
I'm new to Flutter so whatever I found about flutter print bluetooth has different coding, it's confusing.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.